# How to call a CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW statement from Java JPA environment?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, materialized-views

How can I call a CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW statement from my JPA environment? Currently the statement is in a file loaded from the app context. I just want to execute it.

Can I use the EntityManager to execute the sql script or should I create a statement?

```
Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
SessionFactoryImplementor sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementor) session.getSessionFactory();
ConnectionProvider cp = sfi.getConnectionProvider();
Connection connection = cp.getConnection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute(sql);
```

I tried that but just received a "missing identifier \n". Maybe this is because my statement starts with a new line, but that should not be the problem. The script itself is okay and works when executed by SQL*Plus for instance.

In addition I tried it with

```
em.createNativeQuery(sql);
```

but received "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet".

Any thoughts or examples?

ad: I am using Oracle 12c in the back.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after some hours of hooking deeper I found my problem(s).

First of all, my sql script was containing unescaped " (double quotes). The solution was to escape these characters.

Nevertheless, the most tricky thing was that all my sql files had containing \uFEFF signs. Known as BOM (byte order mark). It seems my Oracle driver is not in the position to handle BOMs correctly. This caused the \n exception as mentioned above.

Finally, I am able to call

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.executeUpdate();
```

in order to create my materialized views. Lessons learned: Keep attention to unrecognized signs in sql files.